# React Setting input value to value in a state array

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a React-Bootstrap `FormControl` and I am trying to set the state with the following:

```
<FormGroup controlId={0} key={0} >
     <FormControl onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.form_answers[0]} />
 </FormGroup>
```

This.state.form_answers is being set in the constructor like so:

```
this.state = ({
  form_answers : ['foo','bar','foo-bar'],
});
```

My handle change function is updating the state with the following:

```
handleChange(event) {
  let form_answers = this.state.form_answers;
  form_answers[parseInt(event.target.id)] = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    form_answers : form_answers,
  });
}
```

The state is being updated correctly, but the value displayed on the input field is not changing at all. I am also getting the following error message:

> warning.js:36 Warning: FormControl is changing an uncontrolled input
>   of type undefined to be controlled. Input elements should not switch
>   from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using
>   a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
>   component.

When I set `FormControl` to the following it works:

```
<FormGroup controlId={0} key={0} >
     <FormControl onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.form_answers[0]} />
 </FormGroup>


handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    my_test_state: event.target.value,
  });
}
```

However, since I am creating multiple FormControl elements dynamically, the working solution is not feasible. Is it not possible to set the input value to an state index value? If it isn't possible, then could someone please give me advice on how best to update/set values for dynamically created input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The state is being updated correctly, but the value displayed on the input field is not changing at all

Are you sure? I did a local test and the state was NOT updating correctly because `controlId` is a property of `FormGroup` not `FormControl`. That is, `FormControl` will inherit the `controlId` value for its `id` if it's not set.

When I switched `controlId` to `id` in `FormControl` it worked as expected.

Comment: You are correct, that was my fault. I changed some parts of my code before posting to make a minimal example, and accidently added controlId to FormControl. I changed the FormControl/FormGroup to be exactly the same as in my code... Sorry about that mate. I appreciate the answer though

Comment: No problem, but like I said it works for me locally. So you must have changed something else too when posting.

Comment: Hmm thanks boss. It must be something with my state that I'm not seeing then. I'll accept your answer for the A+ detective work and confirming that it must be something with my state. Have a good one @Jack

Comment: Sure, if you continue to have problems then just update your question with your full class/code as-is and @ me and I'll take another look.